# I don't understand why this scenario is checkmate. The black rook cannot move, as it's protecting black king. Can someone explain? See photo

Tags: endgame, checkmate, queens, kings, rooks

[image]

So in this scenario the White Queen put the black king in check, which was then blocked by the black rook. So, how is it that the black queen moving to the position of F1 is considered checkmate? The white king could take the black queen, since the black rook cannot move. Can someone explain that please?

Comment: The White King may not move into check. It is that simple. The fact that the Black Rook can't move (due to the pin) is irrelevant.  **Kings may not move into check.**

Comment: A pity it's closed. If a pinned black rook on f7 would not be considered checking a white king that took KxQf1, because a check was something only given by pieces free to take the king on the next move, i.e. not pinned to their own king themselves.. Imagine, in that logic, a stripped position resembling the one above: W: Ke1, Qc4, Rc1, Ra4 B: Kg8, Qf1, Rf7, Ba6, (pawn)c3. Now 1.Qc4xQf1 Rf7xf1# would have to follow, cos 1.KxQf1 is illegal, cos the Rf7 could take the Kf1 cos the Qc4 could not take the Kg8 cos the Ba6 could take the Kf1. The ultimate free piece in the line defines what is check.